# Why do I get "fb conversion error from string "0"" error when using a normal query?

Tags: delphi, firebird, rad-studio

I'm new to Delphi and Firebird. When I run the following query, I get an error:

> fb conversion error from string "0"

`RECEIPTDATE` is a `DATE` column.

How should I change my query?

```
FDQueryDataBetween.SQL.Add('select * from RAPOR where RECEIPTDATE BETWEEN '+startDate+' AND '+stopDate+'');
```

Comment: Which version of Firebird are you using, and which SQL dialect does your DB use? There are differences between Dialect 1 and Dialect 3 when formatting date strings manually. What string values do `startDate` and `stopDate` contain? See [Firebird Date Literals](https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-date-literals/) for the supported formats. But why are you building up the SQL statement manually at all? Use a [parameterized query](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Executing_Commands_(FireDAC)#Using_Parameters) instead, let Firebird itself handle the formatting for you.

Comment: I am using firebird 3. startDate and stopDate type is TDate. I need to use a lot query so i use manual query . I think this way useful for me. I will search parameterized query.

Comment: You REALLY should not use manual queries when parameter values are involved. They are inefficient, and dangerous if you get them wrong (SQL injection attacks, etc). Use parameterized queries instead. They are safer, faster, and more efficient, especially if you need to execute the same queries many times. A parameterized query can be prepared ahead of time on the server end, and then you just execute it as many times as you need providing only the new parameter values each time, not whole new querries.

Comment: Do NOT concatenate strings to build SQL. Not only does it leave you open to SQL injection, but it causes problems with quoting values, conversion issues and other problems. Use parameters instead, which allows the database drivers to resolve all of the above issues. There are dozens of existing posts here about using parameterized queries in Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with using parameters.

```pascal
FDQueryDataBetween.SQL.Add('select * from RAPOR where RECEIPTDATE BETWEEN :startDate AND :stopDate');
FDQueryDataBetween.ParamByName('startDate').AsDate:= DateTimePickerStart.Date;
FDQueryDataBetween.ParamByName('stopDate').AsDate:= DateTimePickerEnd.Date;
```